# We flip a fair coin 10 times. What is the probability that we get heads in exactly 8 of the 10 flips?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-distribution

We flip a fair coin 10 times. What is the probability that we get heads in exactly 8 of the 10 flips?

I thought the answer was this:
P (Heads  ≥ 8 flips)  =  P( Tails ≤ 2 flips )  =

C(10,0)(1/2)^10   + C(10,1) (1/2)^10  + C(10,2)(1/2)^10  =  7 / 128

But it is wrong. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: P(Heads ≥ 8 flips) is not the same as P(Heads exactly = 8 flips)...

Comment: Yes, you've computed the probability that you get 8 or more heads, not exactly 8 heads.

Comment: Total outcomes: $2^{10}$. Favorable outcomes: $\binom{10}{8}$

Comment: Try the binomial theorem, we know each flip as probability $1/2$ so $p=1/2$, with $n=10$ trials and $x=8$ heads, therefore $\binom{10}{8}(1/2)^8(1/2)^2$

Comment: @Stackcans so $\frac{45}{1024}?$

Comment: @CastawayFly That seems reasonable to me - do you understand why we chose the binomial theorem for this question? For a probability mass function, we look out for terms such as: 'exactly', 'is equal to', and anything that my represent 'a = b'. Whereas, when choosing the distribution function as you did, we have terms such as: 'at least', 'at most', 'more than', 'greater than', and adjust accordingly. I.e. 'choose at most 8' is $P(X \le 8)$, whereas 'choose at least 8' is $P(X \ge 8)$, so then 'choose exactly 8', is $P(X = 8)$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use binomial theorem to solve this problem.

$n$ = number of tosses (here, $n = 10$)

$p$ = probability of success (here, $p = {1 \over 2}$ as you have a fair coin)

$q$ = probability of failure (here, $q = 1 - p = {1 \over 2}$ )

The probability of exactly $k$ heads in $n$ tosses with a fair coin is given by

$ P(X = k) = \left( \matrix{ n \cr k \cr} \right) \ p^k q^{n - k}$

Taking $k = 8$ (exactly 8 heads), we get the required probability as follows:

$P(X = 8) = \left( \matrix{ 10 \cr 8 \cr} \right) \ 
\left( {1 \over 2} \right)^8  \left( {1 \over 2} \right)^{(10 - 8)} $

Note that

$\left( \matrix{ 10 \cr 8 \cr} \right) = \left( \matrix{ 10 \cr 2 \cr} \right) = {10 \times 9 \over 2 \times 1} = 45$.

Thus,

$P(X = 8) = 45 \left( {1 \over 2} \right)^8  \left( {1 \over 2} \right)^{2} $

*i.e.*

$P(X = 8) = 45 \left( {1 \over 2} \right)^{10}$

Simplifying, we get

$P(X = 8) = {45 \over 2^{10}} = {45 \over 1024} = 0.0439$.

Answer (score 0):

probability of getting head tossing the coin is `1/2`
and also probability of getting head tossing the coin is `1/2`

and same sample space for n coins tossed 1 time or 1 coin tossed n times.

the probability of exactly 8 heads is

[click on this image to the step-wise solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VmCo.png)

Comment: For any doubts please post, i will answer on this platform. Thanking from https://www.mathematicsoptional.com/

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.